# How to copy a subfolder into a subfolder using xcopy?

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy

Let's say I'm in `C:\test` directory, where I have `C:\test\myHugeFolder` directory and a `C:\test\backup` directory - and I'd like to copy `myHugeFolder` into `backup` from `cmd.exe` Command Prompt.

So, I thought this usage of `xcopy` is correct, by using relative paths:

```
C:\test> xcopy myHugeFolder backup\ /s /e
```

The thing is, `xcopy` here was churning for like 15 minutes, also listing each file in `myHugeFolder`, so I thought all was fine - then when it finished, I look into `backup`, and there no `myHugeFolder`; in fact when I search for `myHugeFolder`, there's only the original:

```
C:\test>dir myHugeFolder* /s
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is FFFF-FFFF

 Directory of C:\test

18-10-2015  16:26    <DIR>          myHugeFolder
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               1 Dir(s)  2.419.708.346.368 bytes free
```

So, obviously that is not the right command line - where am I going wrong, and what is the right invocation of `xcopy` to do this kind of a copy?

Comment: Your command works here.

Comment: Thanks @Noodles - I should have clarified: I now learned that with that invocation, only contents are copied, and the folder in itself is not duplicated, which is what I wanted (and what the Unix command `cp -a myHugeFolder backup\` would have done).

Comment: Just FYI, you should probably be using `robocopy` instead of `xcopy`.  Neither is perfect, but `robocopy` has more options, can cope with long paths, and will retry if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test in the question is wrong.

```
C:\test> dir myHugeFolder
```

This command will not list anything copied to the *C:\test\backup* folder.

A correct test is more like this:

```
C:\test> dir backup
```

It would show that the contents of *C:\test\myHugeFolder* was copied into *C:\backup*, not *C:\test\backup\myHugeFolder*.

If one wanted a duplicate of *C:\test\myHugeFolder* in *C:\test\backup\myHugeFolder*, one way to do that would be:

```
C:\test> XCOPY myHugeFolder backup\myHugeFolder /E /I
```

After which the following command would show the desired copy of the *myHugeFolder* container:

```
C:\test dir backup\myHugeFolder
```

Comment: Many thanks @kbulgrien - I wanted a duplicate of the folder, not to copy its contents - so I do have to specify the target directory name, and that it be interpreted as directory name `/I`; thanks for that. But I would also need the `/S` switch for recursive, right?

Comment: `XCOPY /?` help tells us that `/E` is `Same as /S /E`, so no, but adding `/S` would not hurt anything if it makes you feel better.